# Representation of $n$-th derivative.

Tags: derivatives, notation

The derivative of a function $y = f(x)$ with respect to $x$ is represented as $\frac{dy}{dx}$

The second derivative is represented as  $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and so on.

Why is it used like this?

Comment: Because that is how the symbol works. It is *not* a fraction, but when (if) you learn more about functions of several variables you will see usage that gives some sense to this.

Comment: "But when and if you learn more..." certainly does not look like a good and helpful comment to me.

Comment: @algevristis It's true though. It's not a good idea to question every tiny bit of notation the moment you see it. Often, the notation is the way it is because it is optimized for some particular use that cannot be explained to beginners that just encountered the topic. In general, questioning the notation is, more often than not, counterproductive, especially for beginners.

Comment: @5xm I understand, there was actually a question from my test which really required me to understand this concept, it was a hairy piece of expression with a basic derivative notation raised to some complex set of powers and the options were all in the above mentioned notation, so I  needed to know how this thing works.

Comment: Please include the test question in your next edit, thanks. I still concur with 5xum, but it is basically very difficult for me to believe that such notation was so freely tampered with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second derivative is the derivative of the derivative, so strictly speaking it is actually
$$
\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx}
$$
Standard fraction simplification rules applied to this expression (even though it's not really a fraction) yields
$$
\frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}
$$
If we, for simplicity, interpret $dx$ as a single symbol rather than a $d$ and an $x$ separate, the parenthesis in the denominator may be elided, and we're left with
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
$$

---

Alternatively, the symbol $\frac{d}{dx}$ denotes the operation "take the derivative with respect to $x$". The second derivative is to apply this operation twice, which is to say
$$
\left(\frac d{dx}\right)^2
$$
Again, similar simplifications as above lead us ultimately to the operation "take the second derivative" to be represented by the symbol
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}
$$
and applying it to the function $y$ we write as
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Symbols like $f(x)$ are used to denote the 'output' of a function $f$.  The '$f$' is a rule that assigns a number $f(x)$ to an 'input' $x$.  The rule is arbitrary, but generally given for a specific problem.

Symbols like $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$ are used to denote the 'output' of a derivative operation $\frac{d}{dx}$.  The '$\frac{d}{dx}$' is a rule that assigns a function $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$ to an input $f(x)$.  The rule is arbitrary, but generally given for a specific function.

So when you iterate a function, (compose the function with itself), it's notation is $f^2(x)=(f\circ f)(x)$.  Taking a second derivative yields the same notation

$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2[f(x)]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[{\frac{d}{dx}}[f(x)]\right]=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[f(x)]$$

You can extend this for $n$th order derivatives.

Comment: $f^2(x)$ just as often (or perhaps even more often) means $f(x)*f(x)$.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity that would be $f(x)^2$, from the textbooks and literature that I have seen/used.

Comment: You're lucky. I've seen litterature/textbooks use both meanings.